# How can I create external tables with Hive?

Tags: hive, gcloud, avro, create-table, external-tables

This is the script I run on Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE 'people'(
    'name' string,
    'surname' string,
    'age' string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION
    'gs://directory/subdirectory/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'avro.schema.url'='gs://directory/schema.avsc',
    'transient_lastDdlTime'='1644235388');
```

I get this error:
Error while compiling statement:

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:22 cannot recognize input near ''people'' '(' ''nam'' in table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could you pls enclose them with backtick( `)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `people`(
    `name` string,
    `surname` string,
    `age` string)
...
```